# How to get the contents of a file as a String

Tags: javascript, typescript, sftp, ssh2-sftp

I am new to Typescript and node.
I have this function

```
sftp.connect(config) //CONNECT TO STFP
.then(() => {
    sftp.list(remoteFilePath) //LIST THE FILES IN THE FILEPATH
        .then((list) => {
            list.forEach((index) => { //FOR EVERY FILE IN THE FOLDER, DOWNLOAD IT
                const fileName = remoteFilePath + index.name;
                console.log(fileName);
                sftp.fastGet(fileName, "/Users/Bob/" + index.name)
                    .then((value) => {
                        console.log(value);

                        sftp.end();
                    })
            })
        })
})
// .then(() => {
//     // sftp.end();
// })
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err.message);
});
```

and using the [ssh2-sftp-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client#sec-4-2-6) library. My question is that is it possible for this library to get the contents of the file as opposed to downloading it? I plan on making this function into a lambda function.
At the moment, the variable `value` contains a text telling me that the file has been downloaded to my designated path.

Comment: It looks like you can use [sftp.get](https://github.com/theophilusx/ssh2-sftp-client#sec-4-2-6) with a dst that is a stream or undefined, either loading the data into an existing stream object or returning it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the contents of the file you can read it using the `fs` module after downloading it

```js
// using the ES6 module syntax
import { readFileSync } from "fs"


const data = readFileSync("./file.txt")
```

If you want to get the contents of the file without downloading them to the disk you have to pass a different destination. Use the `ssh2-sftp-client` [get](https://github.com/theophilusx/ssh2-sftp-client#sec-4-2-6) method instead, it accepts a `Stream` or a `Buffer` as the destination. You can use a `Stream` but you have to pipe it somewhere. Here's an example using `process.stdout` which is a writable stream:

```js
// ...
stfp.get(
    fileName, "/Users/Bob/" + index.name,
    process.stdout
)
```